# How to find closest neighbors from start node to end in json object

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JSON data and there a lot of UUID in it. Under each UUID there are neighboring uuids that are connected to it.

I'm trying to get list of closest nodes from start node to end.

For example I have a start UUID '5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55' and end UUID '6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443'

I need to find list of UUIDS closest to each other like below

```html
5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55
b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171
0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893
d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6
6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64
4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d
a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca
fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91
42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc
3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31
05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c
6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443
```

Sample data below

```js
var data = [
  {
    "uuid": "5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55",
    "neighbors": [
      "b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171",
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171",
    "neighbors": [
      "5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55",
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
    "neighbors": [
      "5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55",
      "b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
    "neighbors": [
      "5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55",
      "b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171",
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
    "neighbors": [
      "b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171",
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
    "neighbors": [
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
    "neighbors": [
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
    "neighbors": [
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
    "neighbors": [
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
    "neighbors": [
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
    "neighbors": [
      "5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55",
      "b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171",
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
    "neighbors": [
      "5416c2fc2d1d4616bb71cf75d5527e55",
      "b47f2982a5da4fc1abcf89ad4e05a171",
      "0004cde9bb884d889247c9a8278e4893",
      "d249dc582290488c8b37fd163f3d8bc6",
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
    "neighbors": [
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
    "neighbors": [
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
    "neighbors": [
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
    "neighbors": [
      "172d630919c44ee39b08d1a1e907c093",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
    "neighbors": [
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "af4ef4c90057441bb405c20b63240022",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
    "neighbors": [
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
    "neighbors": [
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
    "neighbors": [
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
    "neighbors": [
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
    "neighbors": [
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "6239cee3fe974e29bd5a1c3a59977c64",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91",
    "neighbors": [
      "cc8e1fd645c942c0907001600924c973",
      "250915499a9c43158876b43de9672940",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443"
    ]
  },
  {
    "uuid": "6d0f67c27a7040968d983593ca9ba443",
    "neighbors": [
      "9de62c08cba44371a5585922378e46e3",
      "55bff8fd8c9141569daf1fb5d14aa44d",
      "4b06f6a10e2c4c2394c4519b253a796d",
      "a63fc06e342247cf8a01e3d36658f4ca",
      "e1ab73ad59084a9fa19f8cb641cc5067",
      "dc427cfe95c54d2cb03c96067208ae55",
      "342fc760eece4192b6cdee3f88d20f2a",
      "08dcb94469c042b4a4d4e45e4bce82c8",
      "a99c889c8b37473b9724f98a008fcf8a",
      "f339b3510ce547fd8acdcf6782941b3a",
      "05495baf6bc84fd4ae905a2cfad2281c",
      "3b1fc546dc4349979c243b2905947a31",
      "42e366a7b3f44413bcff26c59d171afc",
      "fe4859bbe9104db79834cc208361ee91"
    ]
  }
];
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I have a json object* There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string format.

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: What do you mean by "closest"? Is there are distance associated with a neighbor? Are you trying to find the shortest path? Try the Dijkstra algorithm

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with JSON or the format of your data, and everything to do with graph theory. You'll get much better help if you restructure your question, and drop the UUIDs for something more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bergi "shortest path" is the right keyword for searching. It really helped me. Also checking the Dijkstra, many thanks.